# Get the cell in a row and column (Cocoa)

Tags: swift, nstableview

I need to get the cell contained in a column at a specified row without using the tableview functions. For example:

```
for a in 0...tableview!.numberOfRows {
    let column = tableview.tableColumns[2]
    let cell = cell in column at the row a
}
```

Do you have any solutions?

EDIT: in Cocoa

Comment: Use `0..<tableview!.numberOfRows`

Comment: Is a "cell" a `NSTableCellView`? Why can't you use `NSTableView` method `view(atColumn:row:makeIfNecessary:)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with this (to retrieve the values of an item in each cell), thanks Willeke

```
for a in 0...tableview!.numberOfRows-1 {
     let cell = tableview.view(atColumn: 2, row: a, makeIfNecessary: false) as? cella
     print(cell?.tipo.title)
}
```